# Is there a standardised test for focus?

Tags: test, concentration, standardized

Not affiliated with psychology in any way, so my knowledge is essentially zero.
I am looking for a way to measure change in my ability to focus during a fast. This is simply for a personal experiment.
I had a look online and could not find a standardised tests used in research.

Any help in finding one is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: edited to clarify that I am not looking for life advice. I am looking for a standardized test used in psychology research to measure my ability to focus (concentration a task?).

Comment: Related: [Neurophysiological indications of focus and motivation](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8925/7001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eye tracking + Posner queuing seems to predict it decently well

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnhum.2013.00205/full

> Numerous studies conducted within the recent decades have utilized the Posner cuing paradigm for eliciting, measuring, and theoretically characterizing attentional orienting.

Example of study:

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32984203/

> To elicit endogenous and exogenous shifts of attention, we thus used a modified version of Posner's cueing task. We compared oculomotor performance measured by an eye tracker in a group of 31 children with ADHD (mean age = 9.1 ± 1.3 years) and age-, sex-, and IQ-matched typically developing children [...]